# Show that is A is an infinite set, it is numerically equivalent to a subset of itself.

Tags: real-analysis

I know that an infinite set has a countably infinite subset, but not sure how to use this to prove the statement.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind-infinite_set#Proof_of_equivalence_to_infinity,_assuming_axiom_of_countable_choice

Answer (score 0):

Once you have that the infinite set has a countably infinite subset, you should know that -a countable set is equivalent to a subset of itself.  For example, the integers are equivalent to the naturals.  You can make a bijection by making the countable subset be equivalent to a subset of itself and letting the rest of the infinite set go to itself.  Chaining notions like this is very important in infinite combinatorics.

Answer (score 0):

Let $ C \subseteq A$ be a countable subset of $A$.We can represent $C =\{a_1,\dots\}$ and let $B = \{a_{2i} \mid i \in \mathbb{N}\} \subset C$  (Here I have taken $\mathbb{N}$ to be the indexing set for $C$).Now we have natural bijection $g$ between $C$ and $B$ which we will exploit it to find a bijection of $A$ with a proper subset.Define
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
    x  \ &x \in A \setminus C \\
    g(x) \ &x \in C
\end{cases}
$$
Clearly $f$ is a bijection between $A$ and $D$,where $D = (A \setminus C) \cup B \subset A$.